# Cursor on supressed links

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, cursor, hyperlink

I'm using a Link Supressor on a RapidWeaver theme I'm working on. The jQuery code is below. All it does is kill the parent links for drop down menus so that they can't be clicked on. Unfortunately the 'hand' cursor or `pointer` cursor still shows up!

```
// Link Suppressor script by Will Woodgate - visit willwoodgate.com for more information
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li:has(ul)").hover(function() {
        $(this).children("a").addClass("nolink").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

What I want to do is also add the style for `cursor:default;` so that the correct cursor (the default cursor) shows up when you hover over the deadened link! I need to do this part of the styling in the jQuery. That is essential.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're adding a class `nolink` to the `a` elements you could do this simply in CSS:

```
.nolink { cursor: default; }
```

Comment: I understand how to do that, but that just does that to every link! I need it to only happen to the parents of the sub menus! This is why the style probably needs to be implemented within the jQuery.

Comment: What's the problem with putting it on every link? It would make more sense semantically that way IMO.

Comment: Well I really want the sub menu items to show a hand when they're hovered over but the parent items are just being used as headings, and because of the setup I've got for the nav it wouldn't work. Here's a screenshot. http://cdn.jeremyblaze.com/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-28%20at%2011.32.55%20PM.png

Comment: Hand on a second... your code works. I see what you did - apologies. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @JeremyBlazé no problem, glad to help. Don't forget to click the green tick to the left if this answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are related threads on RW support forums, for example here 
http://forums.realmacsoftware.com/discussion/60662/change-pointing-finger-to-cursor
where I've explained what is "nolink" class for and posted links to articles on subject (as there is no built-in solution in RW yet for links supression).

best,
Peter